# Hide iOS/mobile address bar in galleria fullscreen mode

Tags: javascript, jquery, drupal, galleria

I'm putting together a responsive galleria slideshow on a drupal site with the [galleria](https://drupal.org/project/galleria) module and the galleria 'twelve' theme, using [omega](https://drupal.org/project/omega/) as my drupal base theme. Everything is working very well, except that when I enter fullscreen on my iPod I can't get rid of the address bar. I'd also like to make the bottom toolbar go away if possible. Together they take up quite a bit of space.

Any suggestions? I've seen a few methods to accomplish this (in a more general way, not specific to galleria) with some javascript, but that's not my strong suit, and I wouldn't know how to implement those solutions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To hide the address bar on iOS you just need to scroll the page a little

```
window.onload = function() {
    // x/y coordinates, "1" will cause the address bar to hide
    window.scrollTo(0, 1);
};
```

The bottom bar can't be hidden while in the browser. However, you can add the website to the home screen which will make hiding the address bar and bottom toolbar possible by adding a meta tag:

```
<meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes">
```

Comment: ...and, for this to work, the content must presumably be longer than the viewport so that it can actually scroll.

Comment: scronide is right, obviously the page needs to be at least as high as the viewport w/o the address bar. However, this opens another can of worms, especially if you want to consider pages which are normally smaller.

Comment: Okay, I've got something semi-working. I changed galleria to set the body and the container to ~120% instead of 100%, which gets the address bar off the screen, but leaves me with some blank space at the bottom of the screen. You're right, Torsten. Galleria wants to set the fullscreen view to fill the viewport exactly, so by default the page won't be long enough to scroll. I'll just have to play around with it.

Comment: And that was actually not a good solution. It doesn't work at all on larger screens (e.g. iPad), as the image becomes larger than the viewport. I know this sort of thing is possible (see e.g. http://judithpeck.net/portfolio.html). I should probably just bite the bullet and pay for slideshowpro.

Comment: The thing with viewport height is that there is currently now known solution to really work reliably across platforms. For iOS it just works to have the viewport higher than visible when the page loads or rotates and set the correct height right afterwards. To make this work reliably on Android as well you'll have to incorporate a lot of workarounds or disable this solution.